# Do apps compiled with kinect sdk beta still work with new runtime frameworks

Tags: c#, xaml, kinect

I have an app that was created in kinect sdk beta and I need to execute it in an app that I am creating. My current project is with sdk beta but in the future the whole is going to be ported to the latest kinect sdk. So my question is: will that original app still be executed and still run with the latest microsoft kinect frameworks, drivers etc???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created an app on BETA SDK and it runs perfectly with newly installed drivers (obtained by simply connecting a kinect to a usb port) So i suppose they are still included and still run perfectly. But the future is foggy because when the SDK moved from beta to the official it also moved "offices" (from Microsoft Research to Microsoft IEB) and many breaking changes where introduced including namespaces so it is unclear whether they will still run

Answer (score 0):

When the Kinect for Windows SDK changes from the beta (produced by Microsoft Research), to the official version (produced by Microsoft IEB) there where several breaking changes, including namespace changes. Therefore you are not able to simply upgrade the assemblies to the latest version without changing the code first.

The drivers have also been updated to reflect changes in the API, and additional functionality added in the latest version. So you will need to update the whole package.

Microsoft have however kept the original research beta assemblies available for download, in-case this causes issues so you can still obtain them if required.

Comment: you only told me about the code and the sdks, I am asking about ready apps and frameworks... is it the same with them aswell?

Comment: Yes, it is the same.  An app compiled for the beta will not run if you have the latest SDK (or runtime) installed.